# AutoMapper - Retrieve a different field from a linked source table than the one that links it

Tags: automapper

I have the following table structure that mixes legacy fields with an updated schema:

```
Coaster
  Id (Int)
  ParkId (Int)

Park
  Id (int)
  UniqueId (Guid)
```

So, the Coaster and Park tables are linked using the Park.Id field. The UniqueId field is not currently used in the old schema. We are migrating to a clean DB using AutoMapper, and this new schema looks like this:

```
Coaster
  Id (Int)
  ParkId (Guid)

Park
  Id (Guid)
```

The problem I am having is doing this using AutoMapper. I've been experimenting with this code:

```
private ModelMapper()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(x =>
    {
        x.AddProfile<ConvertersMappingProfile>();
    });
}

    // This is the part that I'm trying to work out
    public ConvertersMappingProfile()
    {
            CreateMap<Park, NewSchema.Park>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.ParkId));
    }
```

In the new schema, the Park table's Id matches the old schema's UniqueId.

My question is: Because in the old schema there is no direct link to the UniqueId value of the Park table, how to do I get that value to map to the new schema using the Coaster.ParkId field to Park.Id field mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a custom resolve to fix the problem. So I created my resolver, which pulls up a list of the items in the database (which is typically pretty small) to get all the values from the table I need, and retrieves the value. (Pre-refactored code):

```
public class ParkResolver : IValueResolver<Original.Park, New.Park, string> {
    public string Resolve(Original.Park source, New.Park dest, string destMember, ResolutionContext context) {

        List<Original.Park> list = new List<Original.Park>();

        using (IDbConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Me\Documents\Parks.sql;")) {
            con.Open();
            list = con.Query<Original.Park>($"SELECT * FROM Parks WHERE Id = {source.ParkId}").ToList();
            con.Close();
        }

        return list.FirstOrDefault().UniqueId;
    }
}
```

And I call my custom resolver for the tables I am mapping:

```
        CreateMap<Original.Park, New.Park>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.ParkId, map => map.MapFrom(new ParkResolver()));
```

Hopefully that will help someone else.